# Import AWS Textract in gradle dependency and Java project

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle

I am unable to find any documentation for the following
1. Add dependency in Gradle Java project for AWS Textract
2. What exactly to import for AWS Textract

Can anyone please help or provide pointers?

Answer (score 0):

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-textract
compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-textract', version: '1.11.765'
```

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-textract:1.11.762'

This worked for me.